# Syntax to modify the keys inside a dictionary for-comprehension

Tags: python, for-comprehension

I am running into difficulties trying to create a modified key when manipulating a `dictionary`. Here the key needs to be changed from the original `dict` key to `'x'` plus the dict key. How can that be done?  My attempt is shown:

```
inventory = {k:updateMap(m,
                         {'partNumber': m['part'], 
                          'partName': m['desc'],
                          'bbox': {
                            'xmin' : bboxes[k].x,
                            'xmax' : bboxes[k].x + bboxes[k].w,
                            'ymin' : bboxes[k].y,
                            'ymax' : bboxes[k].y + bboxes[k].h
                          }
                          }) for k,m in 
                                ['x%d' %k1,m1 
                                 for k1,m1 in inventoryRaw.items()]}
```

Here is the syntax error `Unresolved reference m1`:

[image]

How should the nested comprehension be modified?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is the tuple needs to be explicitly spelled out :

```
for k,m in [('x%s'%k1,m1)
```

This works:

```
inventory = {'x%s'%k:updateMap(m,
                     {'partNumber': m['part'], 
                      'partName': m['desc'],
                     'objectClass': 'part',
                      'bbox': {
                        'xmin' : bboxes[k].x,
                        'xmax' : bboxes[k].x + bboxes[k].w,
                        'ymin' : bboxes[k].y,
                        'ymax' : bboxes[k].y + bboxes[k].h
                      }
                      }) for k,m in [('x%s'%k1,m1) 
                          for k1,m1 in 
                                inventoryRaw.items()]}
```